# Discordjs my reaction collector is triggering when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a snippet of code here

```
      const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
      };

      const collector = confirmedMessage.createReactionCollector({filter2, time: 50000});
      collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        console.log("PLEASE");
      });
```

[image]

The collector will trigger regardless of whether I react to thumbs up or thumbs down. May I know why is it happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't use the [`filter` option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions). When you simply pass an object like `{ filter2 }`, you're actually saying `{ filter2: filter2 }`, so there is no `filter` key, just `filter2`.

Try to change your options like this:

```js
createReactionCollector({ filter: filter2, time: 50000 })
```

OR rename `const filter2 =`  to `const filter =` .